# In SSRS are group variables always re-evaluated or cached?

Tags: variables, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

In an SSRS report I've got a row group for which a handful of variables are defined; i.e. they are defined at the group not the report level. Some of the variables are a function of the other variables.

Within the context of a row is the value for the variable at that row re-evaluated each time the variable is referenced (either to display in a tablix or as part of a another variable's calculation) or are the values evaluated once for each row and cached for subsequent display and calculations?

Comment: I added a grpVar or Variables!grpvar.Value. For some reason I witnessed very slow processing when I had LONG column groups. After taking out the vars and added just a straight up integer value for group values it was more in line with performance I had been excpecting.

Comment: @Irb can you elaborate? I am not following exactly what you did.